# Is there any way to shorten if statement with bitwise or?

Tags: c, if-statement, bitwise-or

Is there a way to shorten the if statement with the bitwise or and strcmp?

```
if 
(strcmp(level, array[1])==0||
strcmp(level, array [2])==0||
strcmp(level, array [3])==0)
{
/*Code*/
}
```

The goal is to shorten the code of if statement

Comment: You could shorten it with bitwise OR, but that would likely guarantee 3 comparisons instead of allowing for early exiting. Don't over-complicate your code for the sake of shortness. Use the correct operations for the semantics you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I see no way to "shorten" the `if` statement. However, if you have hundreds of such strings, you may want to consider putting all of the strings into a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), to make the search for the matching string more efficient.

Comment: At least use a `for` loop. Code like that is not sustainable.

Comment: Are you deliberately skipping `array[0]`?  In C, arrays typically start with index 0.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @tadman, you can write: `for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) { if ( strcmp( level, array[i] ) == 0 ) { /*Code*/ break; } }` If you have more than 3 comparisons, then this will shorten the code significantly.

Comment: @abelenky Yes, i forgot to put array [0] sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by shortening?

Comment: rename `array` to `a` and level to `l` then `#define s strcmp(l,a[` and you can write `if(s 1])||s 2])||s 3]))  { /* .... */}` As a bonus everyone will wonder how it can compile :) (but you need to hide the #define somewhere deep in your project